# Take value from data in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I want to take value cuisine from table a in column a with value `- ak://food/category?pageTitle=Minuman&cuisine=MINUMAN&sortBy=1`. The result I want is `MINUMAN`. How to take value cuisine?

Answer (score 1):

Use below as an example

```
select regexp_extract('ak://food/category?pageTitle=Minuman&cuisine=MINUMAN&sortBy=1', r'\bcuisine=(\w+)\b')
```

with output

[image]

Comment: thank you! how about take pageTitle `ak://food/category?pageTitle=Pasti%20Ada%20Promo&option=3&sortBy=1` ?

Comment: use something like - `regexp_extract(uri, r'\bpageTitle=([^&]+)[&$]')` with output `Pasti%20Ada%20Promo`

Comment: have you tried? does it work for you?

Comment: yaa, thank you. I try that but also using replace to erase the percentage